# Excel: Identifying the reference row used in final result of an array formula

Tags: arrays, excel

Have been using stackoverflow as reference to build an excel project I've been working on. Alas, this is a problem I have not been able to find a solution, despite many tries. Hoping someone can help here, many thanks in advance!

Sample data is as below (actual data is more complicated but have condensed it to the essentials for simplicity):

[image: Sample data]

Column I has an array formula which finds the minimum value of the sum of Objects A+B for each ID (still grasping the concept of array formulas, so it might look more cluttered than it could be):

```
{=IF(E2="A",MIN(IF(D2&"B"=$F$2:$F$8,G2+$H$2:$H$8)),MIN(IF(D2&"A"=$F$2:$F$8,H2+$G$2:$G$8)))}
```

I am interested in using the variable row reference that is used to compute the final result in the array formula (highlighted in column J in red) for other purposes in the worksheet. Is there any way to return this result?

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted as per sample, then this should be workable.

Btw, I really appreciate this though :

> (actual data is more complicated but have condensed it to the essentials for simplicity)

Here's my way (put in J2 then drag downwards) :

```
=IF(E2="A",G2,H2)

+

IF(
    COUNTIF(
        INDIRECT("$F$2:F"&(MATCH(D2&IF(E2="A","B","A"),$F$2:$F$8,0)+1),TRUE),
        INDIRECT("F"&(MATCH(D2&IF(E2="A","B","A"),$F$2:$F$8,0)+1),TRUE)
        )=1,

    MIN(
        OFFSET(
            INDIRECT("G"&(MATCH(D2&IF(E2="A","B","A"),$F$2:$F$8,0)+1),TRUE),
            0,
            IF(INDIRECT("E"&(MATCH(D2&IF(E2="A","B","A"),$F$2:$F$8,0)+1),TRUE)="B",1,0),
            COUNTIF($F$2:$F$8,INDIRECT("F"&(MATCH(D2&IF(E2="A","B","A"),$F$2:$F$8,0)+1),TRUE)),
            1
            )

        )

    ,""

)
```

Idea : use offset with indirect, to define the min() range. With some 'idea' of index match, the min() values are called.

Kindly refer the [reference file](https://utpmy-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/mohammad_g03606_utp_edu_my/ES9lLh-Ah9RAi7wBouv-8dkBdtRAh1hl7r2P47IBi1obDA?e=Ta0axo) for clearer breakdown/source of the EACH code section, with some learning curve.

Kindly share if it works/not/understandable. /(^_^)